# Passing a variable twice in Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables

I want the command: `echo "$string4"` to return me the values of the `SETFIELDS_X_XX` variables defined in the beginning of my file, during the loop. However, it only returns me the *name* `SETFIELDS_X_XX`. What am I doing wrong?

```
SETFIELDS_2_25=225
SETFIELDS_2_200=2200
SETFIELDS_2_500=2500
SETFIELDS_10_25=1025
SETFIELDS_10_200=10200
SETFIELDS_10_500=10500
SETFIELDS_10_1000=101000
SETFIELDS_50_25=5025
SETFIELDS_50_200=50200
SETFIELDS_50_500=50500
SETFIELDS_50_1000=501000

for LBUB in 2 10 50
do
    for generations in 25 200 500 1000
    do
        string1="SETFIELDS_"
        string2="$LBUB"
        string3="_$generations"
        string4=$string1$string2$string3
    #echo "LBUB = $LBUB"
    #echo "generations = $generations"
    echo "$string4"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
echo ${!string4}
```

It will print the value stored inside the variable SETFIELDS_X_XX

Comment: Remove quotes from variable assignment of string1,2 and 3, then try.

Comment: The quotes wouldn't cause this error. Is the OP sure he is using `bash`?

Comment: Tried and not working as well. It is weird because it seems it is not recognizing the `!`...  it gets red and bold in my code

Comment: Are you sure you are using bash shell, as it is working for me.

Comment: Hi chepner, yes I am using bash.. I have the first line `#!/bin/sh
`, just did not put it in the question

Comment: `#!/bin/sh ` is not a bash shell, its a Bourne shell (sh). A bash shell is usually defined with `#!/bin/bash`. For more information please read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: hm, sorry, my bad. Now it is working! Thanks you guys!

Comment: @LisandroMaders seems like you forgot to accept the answer

Comment: Yes I did.. sorry!